# Binary operator '-=' cannot be applied to operends of type 'CGFloat' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am currently making an app using Swift by following a tutorial. When I run the code in XCode, I get the error stated in the title. Here is my code:

```
    import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var currentLevel = 0
    var currentLevelData:NSDictionary
    var levels:Levels
    var bg:SKSpriteNode
    var man:SKSpriteNode
    var levelType:SKSpriteNode
    var manSpeed = 10
    var runningManTextures = [SKTexture]()
    var stageMaxLeft:CGFloat = 0
    var stageMaxRight:CGFloat = 0
    var x: CGFloat = 0

    var manLeft = false
    var manRight = false


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        stageMaxRight = self.size.width / 2
        stageMaxLeft = -stageMaxRight
        loadLevel()
    }

    func loadLevel() {
        currentLevelData = levels.data[currentLevel]
        loadBackground()
        loadLevelType()
        loadMan()
    }

    func loadBackground() {
        var bgNum = currentLevelData["bg"] as! String
        bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg_\(bgNum)")
        bg.name = "bg"
        bg.zPosition = 1.0
        scene!.addChild(bg)
    }

    func loadLevelType() {
        var levelTypeInfo = currentLevelData["type"] as! String
        levelType = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: levelTypeInfo)
        levelType.name = "level_type"
        levelType.position.y = -140
        levelType.zPosition = 2.0
        scene!.addChild(levelType)
    }

    func loadMan() {
        loadManTextures()
        man.position.y -= man.size.height/2
        man.position.x = -(scene!.size.width/2) + man.size.width * 2
        man.zPosition = 3.0
        addChild(man)
    }

    func loadManTextures() {
        var runningAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "run")
        for i in 1...3 {
            var textureName = "run_\(i)"
            var temp = runningAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            runningManTextures.append(temp)
        }
    }

    func moveMan(direction:String) {
        if direction == "left" {
            manLeft = true
            man.xScale = -1
            manRight = false
            runMan()
        } else {
            manRight = true
            man.xScale = 1
            manLeft = false
            runMan()
        }

    }

    func runMan() {
        man.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(runningManTextures, timePerFrame: 0.2, resize:false, restore:true)))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches:, Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if event.allTouches()!.count == 1 {
            let location = touches.first().locationInNode(self) //Error(2) reads: Cannot invoke 'locationInNode' with an argument list of type '(GameScene)'.
            if location.x > 0 {
                moveMan("right")
            } else {
                moveMan("left")
            }
        } else {
            println("jump")
        }
    }

    func cancelMoves() {
        manLeft = false
        manRight = false
        man.removeAllActions()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        cancelMoves()
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        self.currentLevel = 0
        self.currentLevelData = [:]
        self.levels = Levels()
        self.bg = SKSpriteNode()
        self.man = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "run_0"))
        self.man.name = "man"
        self.levelType = SKSpriteNode()
        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func cleanScreen() {
        bg.removeFromParent()
        levelType.removeFromParent()
    }

    func nextScreen(level:Int) -> Bool {
        if level >= 0 && level < levels.data.count {
            currentLevel = level
            currentLevelData = levels.data[currentLevel]
            cleanScreen()
            loadBackground()
            loadLevelType()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func updateManPosition() {
        if man.position.x < stageMaxLeft {
            if nextScreen(currentLevel - 1) {
                man.position.x = stageMaxRight
            }
            if manLeft {
                return
            }
        }
        if man.position.x > stageMaxRight {
            if nextScreen(currentLevel + 1) {
                man.position.x = stageMaxLeft
            }
            if manRight {
                return
            }
        }

        if manLeft {
            man.position.x -= manSpeed //error here
        } else if manRight {
            man.position.x += manSpeed //error here also
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        updateManPosition()
    }
}
```

I know this is probably a really dumb question, but I am stumped. I've already searched around, and I found a question similar, but the solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, the compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is here, the compiler isn't letting you mix types. The problem is here:

```
var manSpeed = 10
```

That is implicitly creating manSpeed as an Int. So when you try to -= it with a CGFloat (which is what man.position.x is) the compiler is complaining:

```
if manLeft {
        man.position.x -= manSpeed //error here
    } else if manRight {
        man.position.x += manSpeed //error here also
    }
```

The best way to fix this is to explicitly type manSpeed

```
var manSpeed: CGFloat = 10.0
```

That will make sure that the types match

Comment: This fixed it! I guess that tutorial is way out of date. I copied everything he did exactly, but that wasn't the first thing I had to change up.

Comment: I actually have one more question, if you don't mind my asking. I don't want to feel like a bother!

Comment: If it's related, ask here. Otherwise, make a new question.

Comment: It's related to this exact code, but I'm not necessarily sure if you can count that. I'll put a comment where the error is, you can tell me if I should make a new question.

Comment: In this case, touches.first() will return an NSObject? type, so you will likely need to unwrap it before calling locationInNode

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to unwrap it. I'm following a tutorial, and I literally know zilch about all of this. I'm really sorry for being such an inconvenience. I really thank you for the help, though!